# Pdf generated using domtoimage ,jspdf is differed from original HTML page

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

As I want to convert my html into pdf ,I used domtoimage to convert the html into pdf.The pdf was generated but not exactly as how it displayed in original html...As I am pretty new to this domtoimage..I can't figure out the exact solution.I referred the other questions similar to this but none of the solutions are worked out here..
HTML image : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhWHw.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr6w5.png
Pdf image: [pdf generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhWHw.png)

domtoimage conversion code:

```
this.loadImage(this.depoLogoPath).then((logo) => {
    const div = document.getElementById('content');
    const options = { background: 'white', allowTaint: true};
    domtoimage.toPng(div, options).then((dataUrl) => {
      const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'letter');
      var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);
      doc.save('pdfDocument.pdf');
    });});
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's set to generate an image in portrait orientation when it should be landscape.

It should be:

> const doc = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'letter');